# 'Show Desktop' Mission Control/Expose Not Functioning [OSX 10.7 Lion]

Tags: macos, osx-lion, expose, mission-control

I have recently upgraded to OS X Lion. I have mapped the keys via Mission Control preFpane as follows: F9 is 'Mission Control', F10 is 'Show Desktop'. F11 is 'Application Windows'

F9 and F11 works as intended. F10 seems to not do anything.

I thought it might be the keys themselves so I mapped the keys as: F9 'Show Desktop', F10 'Mission Control' and F11 'Application Windows'.

In this case only F10 and F11 keys worked; This small test gives me the impression that it is the Exposé 'Show Desktop' function itself is the part that is malfunctioning.

Does anybody have any further insight to this bug?

***EDIT***

You can view a recording of the problem here:
http://www.screencast.com/t/oDVMhBqkb

***NOTE***

This problem was tested initially on my external keyboard, the problem does persist on the internal macbook keyboard. Those '4 finger swipe' works, as does the 'Cmd + Expose(f3)' keyboard shortcut work.

Comment: Does the gesture (4 finger spread) and the old key combination (Cmd + Expose(F3)) work?

Comment: If you go into System Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts, are the hotkeys under Mission Control correctly assigned?

Comment: @bill.cn - Yes, those do work(on my macbook keyboard). Although, note that this is on an external keyboard; Nano8Blazex Yes, it is properly assigned. - http://d.pr/l80W

Comment: I watched your Screenrecording and have no clue why it isn't working. You could leave the standard gestures assigned and reassign them with something like [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/).  Maybe it'll work. What I know for sure and what bugs me like crazy is that "Show Desktop" won't work when apps are in fullscreen (= no dragging screenshots or Zip files on the Desktop into Mail anymore, etc.).

Comment: Any console logs? I would try working from the evidence of that error bell ringing when you press they key. That made me think perhaps something else was claiming the keypress, but of course rebinding like you did disproves that.